# Sum of the first nth term of Series

Tags: python

```
def series_sum(n):
    listSeries = [1, 1/4, 1/7, 1/10, 1/13, 1/16, 1/19, 1/22, 1/25]
    sum = 0.00
    for i in range(n):
        sum += listSeries[i]
    return str("{:.2f}".format(sum))
```

Hey guys, my code passes all tests and kind of works with this challenge, but I get one annoying error, which I don't know how to solve. List index out of range. `list[i-1]` didn't work out. I hope it is not necessary to rewrite the whole code to fix this.
[codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071/train/python](https://codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071/train/python)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(series_sum(15), "1.94")
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 5, in series_sum
    sum += listSeries[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `n` is smaller than `len(list)`?

Comment: By the way, don't use `list` as a variable's name, since it is built-in name.

Comment: you are right about the naming, but n contains integers. n has a variable size.
Here is the actual challange, maybe it helps to have an overview.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071/train/python

Comment: I am sure that you are supposed to generate the coefficients present in `list`. There is a pattern in the denominators, that you are supposed to find and then create a formula for the same. So that any value of n works.

Comment: It's bad idea to name a variable with a inbuilt keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071/train/python) you sent, and I suggest that you generate the list depending on the value of `n` so that you don't get an `IndexError`:

```py
def series_sum(n):
    fractions = []
    for n in range(1, 3*n - 1, 3):
        fractions.append(1/n)
    return "{:.2f}".format(sum(fractions))
```

I tested the code on the website, and it worked for all the solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will approach this solution then. I was hoping, that my solution was almost fine, but I didn't seem like.

Comment: Why call `str()` on a string?

Comment: Good point @SethMMorton, thank you. I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
def series_sum(n):
    return '{:.2f}'.format(sum(1/(1+i*3) for i in range(n)))

print(series_sum(15))
```

Result:

```
1.94
```

Comment: doesn't pass the tests, I posted in the comments above the challange, which I tried to solve

Comment: @Alcyl, I have edited to make it work for your requirement

Comment: @StefanPochmann, python novice here. I think I took your advice to heart and adjusted it accordingly. Care to have a check?

Comment: Yes, looks good now. Funny how the wrong denominators still got the correct result for that input. I think n=15 is the only value where that's the case (other than for the trivial n=0) :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on '{:.2f}' and how you determined (sum(1/(1+i*3)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there are no elements in your list after element at index 8 (Position 9)
So, when you try to use `for i in range(n)` with the value of `n=15`
It gives you an error.

One of the ways you could avoid this, is adding an `if` statement at the top of your code
like this:

```
def series_sum(n):
    l1 = [1, 1/4, 1/7, 1/10, 1/13, 1/16, 1/19, 1/22, 1/25] #You cant use list as a variable name
    if len(l1) < n:
        n = len(l1) #Or do something else here that you wish to do
    #Note: doing n = l1 here will give you the sum of the entire list if n > length of list
    sum = 0.00
    for i in range(n):
        sum += l1[i]
    return str("{:.2f}".format(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only about exceptions on your system. You must be sure for the

```
  len(listSeries) > n
```